# I've created a disaster. Please point out a coding strategy to refactor this

Tags: ruby, refactoring

**UPDATE**

So far I've cut it down significantly:

```
  # Gets the user's Wall
  # I used object methods so they can be called by other methods, such as #second_wall()
  def read_wall(fbuserid)
     @result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
  end

  def second_wall(fbuserid)
     @second ||= @result.next_page
  end

  def third_wall(fbuserid)
     @third ||= @second.next_page
  end

  def fourth_wall(fbuserid)
       fourth ||= @third.next_page
   end

  # Collects your friends' wall Posts and puts the IDs into an array
  # the number array contains method names that will be called
  # This is done to read 100 wall posts
  def get_post_ids(fbuserid)
     var = []   
     number = [read_wall(fbuserid), second_wall(fbuserid), third_wall(fbuserid), fourth_wall(fbuserid)]
     number.each do |iterate|
        num ||= iterate
        for i in 0..25
           if find_nil(num, [i,'id']).nil? == false
              var << num[i]['id']
           end
        end
     end
```

Originally, I had everything in the base method #read_wall(). I'm not sure what happened with the array, but when I tried:

`array = result + second + third + fourth`. I was left with data from only the original result. So I created this working disaster. **Can you please help me refactor this?**

```
   # Gets the user's Wall
      def read_wall(fbuserid)
         result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
      end

  def second_wall(fbuserid)
     result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
     second ||= result.next_page
  end

  def third_wall(fbuserid)
       result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
       second ||= result.next_page
       third ||= second.next_page
  end

  def fourth_wall(fbuserid)
        result ||= graph.get_connections(fbuserid, 'feed')
        second ||= result.next_page
        third ||= second.next_page
        fourth ||= third.next_page
   end

  # Collects your friends' wall Posts and puts the IDs into an array
  def get_post_ids(fbuserid)
     x ||= read_wall(fbuserid)
     var = []
     for i in 0..25
        if find_nil(x, [i,'id']).nil? == false
           var << x[i]['id']
        end
     end

     second_wall ||= second_wall(fbuserid)
       for i in 0..25
          if find_nil(second_wall, [i,'id']).nil? == false
             var << second_wall[i]['id']
          end
       end

      third_wall ||= third_wall(fbuserid)
        for i in 0..25
           if find_nil(third_wall, [i,'id']).nil? == false
              var << third_wall[i]['id']
           end
        end

      fourth_wall ||= fourth_wall(fbuserid)
         for i in 0..25
            if find_nil(fourth_wall, [i,'id']).nil? == false
                 var << fourth_wall[i]['id']
            end
         end

      @get_post_ids = var
  end
```

Comment: I've voted to close - would this question be suitable for the Code Review Stack Exchange?

Comment: This is a challenging metaprogramming question.

Comment: @Jordan This isn't "challenging meta-programming"; cleaning this up is trivial

Comment: Sarcasm was missed. Deleted it....

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, rather repeating the body of a loop four times on four different arrays, you can make an array of arrays.

Instead of this:

```
for x in array1
  function1(x);
end

for x in array2
  function1(x);
end
```

you can do this:

```
[array1,array2].each do |array|
  for x in array 
    function1(x)
  end
end
```

Comment: This might be helpful. My loops in loops have caused a performance disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a helper function for each specific page does seem like a code smell in this case. It may not always be a problem if you were referring say `user.second_wall` very often and needed a quick way to get to it. However, by linking each such function,

```
read_wall -> second_wall -> third_wall -> fourth_wall
```

it will become incrementally hard to expand and maintain this. Maybe have a base function that can retrieve the wall posts given any user and the desired range.

```
get_wall_posts(user_id, range)
```

To get the first 100 wall posts, and mapping the id's would look something like,

```
first_100_posts = get_wall_posts(some_user, 0...100);
first_100_ids = first_100_posts.map { |post| post['id'] }
```

One of the most important part of refactoring is to give good names to identifiers. Names such as `var` and `iterate` usually don't say much about the code. It is similar to, if not worse, than comments like,

```
// increment i by 1
i++;
```

Consistency is just as important. Groups of methods that do similar things should be named in a consistent manner. `read_wall` and `second_wall` seem to have a disconnect for me because the verb `read` missing from the other methods. `read_second_wall` sounds like a better name, and more inline with the rest.

Another thing to consider in mind with the current design is object consistency. Currently some of the methods are linked by a process (getting the first 100 or 4 pages worth of posts) and not by their individual role, making them dependent on each other. Calling `second_wall` without calling `read_wall` will yield different results because the `result` property has not been initialized yet. That can result in difficult to find bugs because there is another dimension to keep track of - whether object are used in the order expected.

Try to limit the side-effects of functions as much as possible. If an objected must be used in a certain order, then use the [`state`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) pattern or anything similar to ensure that.